# Using GET via URL to load 1 entry from CSV file in PHP

Tags: php

I am using a simple php news script, I want the option to view singular posts (rather than just every post in the file which is how it currently works).

This is the code being used on the front end, I'm quite unsure of what I need to do, but i know it involves a GET parameter...

```
<?php

//get news class and array
include_once('newsadmin/includes/newsTools.class.inc.php');
$newsTools      = new newsTools('newsadmin/csv/news.csv');

    $news_headlines = $newsTools->getNewsArray();
//output news array as formatted html
if (!count($news_headlines)>0){
    echo '<p>There are currently no news headlines.</p>';
}else{
    foreach ($news_headlines as $key => $item){
        list($news_id,$news_date,$news_title,$news_body) = $item;
        $formatted_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a',$news_date);
echo <<<HTML
<a name="$news_id" id="$news_id"></a>
<h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">$news_title</h1>
$news_body
<p><span>Posted: $formatted_date</span></p>
<hr />
HTML;
    }
}

?>
```

I would assume it has something to do with this line:
    foreach ($news_headlines as $key => $item){

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show var_dump of `$news_headlines`?  The reason I ask, is that if there is a associated key that you can reliably use, you can eliminate the need to iterate through the array. Also depending on size of CSV file, have you considered putting data into database of some sort such that you don;t have to parse the entire file and keep the full array structure in memory for each request (even those for a single item)?

Comment: Actually, looking more at your code, it seems that you store the `news_id` value at the same array level as other data.  This is not conducive to id-based lookup. Can you change your `getNewsArray()` method to build the `$news_headlines` array differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to change the `getNewsArray()` method to build your `$news_headlines` array differently.

So instead of having an array like this:

```
[
    ['NEWS ID VALUE', 'NEWS DATE VALUE', 'NEWS TITLE VALUE', 'NEWS BODY VALUE'],
    ['NEWS ID VALUE 2', 'NEWS DATE VALUE 2', 'NEWS TITLE VALUE 2', 'NEWS BODY VALUE 2'],
    ...
]
```

You could build an array like this:

```
[
    'NEWS ID VALUE' => ['NEWS DATE VALUE', 'NEWS TITLE VALUE', 'NEWS BODY VALUE'],
    'NEWS ID VALUE 2' => ['NEWS DATE VALUE 2', 'NEWS TITLE VALUE 2', 'NEWS BODY VALUE 2'],
    ...
]
```

Here the news ID's are the keys in an associative array.  What this does is allow you to lookup news items from the array without having to iterate over the array.  So something like this could be done:

```
//get news class and array
include_once('newsadmin/includes/newsTools.class.inc.php');
$newsTools      = new newsTools('newsadmin/csv/news.csv');

$news_headlines = $newsTools->getNewsArray();

if(!empty($_GET['news_id'])) {
    // a single news item was requested
    $news_id = $_GET['news_id'];
    if (isset($news_headlines[$news_id])) {
        // the news item was found in the array
        $news_item = $news_headlines[$news_id];
        // display your story
        var_dump($news_id,$news_item);
    } else {
        // they requested an invalid news item, show some error here
    }
} else {
    //output news array as formatted html
    if (!count($news_headlines)>0){
        echo '<p>There are currently no news headlines.</p>';
    } else {
        foreach ($news_headlines as $news_id => $item){
            list($news_date,$news_title,$news_body) = $item;
            $formatted_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a',$news_date);
?>
            <a name="<?php echo $news_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $news_id; ?>"></a>
            <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $news_title; ?></h1>
            <?php echo $news_body; ?>
            <p><span>Posted: <?php echo $formatted_date; ?></span></p>
            <hr />
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

If you have a large number of items in your CSV file, you also might want to consider moving this data into a database if possible.  This would prevent the need to load all the data into memory when only a single item is required and would additionally make it easier to do things like sort by date, show records by date range, etc. if you might want to do things like that down the line.

Comment: Hi - thank you so much for your reply - I really do appreciate the time you've it. 
I have an issue however, using your code i am getting this return:
http://dev.pixxl.us/bwc/test.php?id=1

I really am not sure what's happening at all..

This is the display block:
    <a name="<?php echo $news_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $news_id; ?>"></a>
            <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $news_title; ?></h1>
            <?php echo $news_body; ?>
            <p><span>Posted: <?php echo $formatted_date; ?></span></p>

Any ideas? :)

Comment: @JackTrigg I don't understand what the problem is with the webpage you show. It might be helpful if you update your question with your latest code and a description of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for coming back to me - but since I spoke to you last I re-shuffled some bits and got it working beautifully - it's just down to formatting now. Thanks for all of your help - it's really appreciated.